# How Do I use an Else If case in a Function Block

Tags: postgresql, function, if-statement

I am trying to use a function to update a column on a table by creating a function that will do it.

I am trying to create a customer tier based on purchases made by each customer. I know the following code will update my column when I run the command by itself:

```
update email_campaign_detailed 
set customer_tier = 'standard' 
where num_dvd_rented <=20;
```

However I want to use a function to do this so I can input the data and have it auto-rank.
this is the code I'm using that isn't working:

```
Create or replace function customer_tier(num_dvds_rented bigint)
Returns character varying (50)
Language plpgsql
As
$$
Declare
Begin
case
when num_dvd_rented <=20 then update email_campaign_detailed  set customer_tier ='standard'
when num_dvd_rented >= 21 and <= 39 then update email_campaign_detailed  set customer_tier ='silver'
else update email_campaign_detailed  set customer_tier ='gold'
End case;
end;
$$
```

I get a syntax error at the second "when" statement.
I cannot for the life of me figure out what I need to do.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) No `;` at end of UPDATE statement. 2) In `plpgsql` you can use can use [IF/THEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS).

Comment: Are you saying I need a `;` at then end of each update statement?

Comment: Yes, per [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html): *Each declaration and each statement within a block is terminated by a semicolon.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure when using the `case`-expression. Because `case` is an expression, you can just use it in your sql-statement (like any other expression):

```sql
update email_campaign_detailed
set
    customer_tier = case
        when num_dvd_rented <= 20 then 'standard'
        when num_dvd_rented >= 21 and <= 39 then 'silver'
        else 'gold'
    end
where num_dvd_rented <= 20;
```

==== EDIT ===

Your stored procedure doesn't work because you can't have an expression (an `update` statement) within your `when` branches.
I suppose you want to use the `num_dvds_rented` parameter in the stored procedure for your where statement?

```sql
create or replace function customer_tier(num_dvds_rented bigint)
    language plpgsql
As
$$
declare
begin
    update email_campaign_detailed
    set
        customer_tier = case
            when num_dvd_rented <= 20 then 'standard'
            when num_dvd_rented >= 21 and <= 39 then 'silver'
            else 'gold'
        end
    where num_dvd_rented <= num_dvds_rented;
end;
$$
```

Also, your stored procedure doesn't really return anything -- so you don't need the `returns...` in the declaration.

Now, if your goal is to do something like this:

```sql
update email_campaign_detailed
set customer_tier = customer_tier(num_dvd_rented)
where num_dvd_rented <= 20;
```

then your procedure might look like this:

```sql
create or replace function customer_tier(num_dvds_rented bigint)
    returns character varying (50)
    language plpgsql
As
$$
declare
begin
    return case
       when num_dvds_rented <= 20 then 'standard'
       when num_dvds_rented >= 21 and <= 39 then 'silver'
       else 'gold'
    end;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Hi Kristian, I know I don't need a stored procedure but I want a stored procedure. Which is why I asked the question as to what I'm missing to have it as a stored procedure.

Comment: Hi Kristian, THANK YOU!!! that is massively helpful!

Comment: This *...you can't have an expression (an update statement) within your when branches. ...* is wrong. You can have expressions there, see my answer.

Comment: Also you have to have a `RETURNS`. If you are not actually returning anything then `RETURNS void`.

Answer (score 0):

Proof you can have expressions in the `CASE` branches. You just need to terminate then with a `;`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.case_test()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    int_val integer;
BEGIN
CASE WHEN  1 = 1 THEN
    select 1 into int_val;
ELSE
    select 3 into int_val;
END CASE;
RAISE NOTICE 'Val is %', int_val;
END;
$function$
;

select case_test();
NOTICE:  Val is 1
 case_test 
-----------
```